# Javascript prototype behavior

Tags: javascript, prototype, delegation

I have a method that will let me select the prototype object when creating a new object (copied from "Javascript: The Good Parts" book):

```
Object.create = function(o) {
    var F = function() {};
    F.prototype=o;
    return new F();
}
```

Now say, I have an object:

```
var car = {
   model: "Nissan"
};
```

And I create a new object based on this object, using the "Create" method:

```
var car1 = Object.create(car);
```

I can then add a property to car and it will dynamically get added to car1 (dynamic prototyping). So for eg:

```
car.year=2011;      // Gets added to "car"...
alert(car1.year);   // ... Is also avaialable to car1
```

**Q1) This behavior indicates that "year" got added to car's prototype, which is why it is available to car1. Is this correct? If not, then where does "year" get added and why is it available to both "car" and "car1"?**

Also, per the rule of delegation, if a method cannot be found on an object, it will search its prototype and then check all the prototypes up the chain till it gets to Object.prototype. So now, if I type something like this:

```
Object.prototype.originCountry = "Japan";
alert(car.originCountry);   // Outputs Japan
alert(car1.originCountry);  // Outputs Japan
```

So far so good; however, if I do:

```
Object.carColor= "White";
alert(car.carColor);   // Error!
```

**Q2) When I add a property to "car" (see *car.year* example above, it gets added to car's prototype. However, when I add a property to Object, it does not get added to Object's prototype? If it does get added to Object's prototype, then why is it not available to "car", per the rule of delegation?**

Why is this happening?

Comment: I think that behaviour is due to that properties are created on the prototype and if you try to created them from the object itself he throws undefined, and every time you create a property through the prototype every element created with that prototype inherits it.

Comment: Your Q2 starts off wrong: you didn't add anything to `car`'s prototype, you added it to `car1`'s prototype (which happens to be `car`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you do this:

```
Object.carColor = "White";
```

Then the property `carColor` does not get added to the `Object`'s prototype. It is now a property of `Object`. To see what you expect, what you would do is:

```
Object.prototype.carColor = "White";
```

Then after that:

```
alert(({}).carColor); // Will alert "White"
```

So what happens here is that. any object created including `{}` (which is nothing but an empty object) is a new instance of `Object` and hence shares the properties of whatever is set in the prototype of `Object`.

As for how your `Object.create` function works. Let us look at it line-by-line:

```
 1. var F = function() {};
```

You just create a new function, an essentially blank object. The reason you use a function and not something like `{}` is because a function can be coupled with a `new` call to create a new instance of that object wherein the function would act as a constructor.

```
2. F.prototype=o;
```

You set the prototype of the new blank function to the object you've created. Now, this is purely a reference. It is not a deep-copy. What I mean is that as the object `o` changes, so will any instances of the objects (actually they won't change, but they would 'seem to' change. More on that later).

```
3. return new F();
```

Now you just create a new instance of that function, which has a prototype as the object you passed.

When you do the following:

```
var car1 = Object.create(car);
```

You get an object `car1` which has the prototype has `car`. So when you do this:

```
car.year = 2011
```

It isn't like `car1` changes. It is more like the object that the prototype refers to changes. So when you do something like:

```
car1.year
```

A search is made (first in the prototype, then in the object) for a property called `year` and turns out, that the prototype has it and hence `car1.year` will return `2011`.

So the bottom line is this:

1. A prototype is shared amongst instances.
2. Changing the properties of an `Object` will not manifest into any instances changing.

Comment: This is the thing that I am trying to understand. In your post, you said:

[quote]
You get an object car1 which has the prototype has car. So when you do this:

car.year = 2011
It isn't like car1 changes. It is more like the object that the prototype refers to changes.
[/quote]

When I add something to "car" (car.prop = value), why does it get added to its prototype, but when I do the same to Object, it does not.

@Bergi

Comment: What is essentially happening is that `car.year = 2011` is now equivalent of saying `car1.prototype.year = 2011` since `car1.prototype` is nothing but `car`.

Comment: Excuse my lack of knowledge about this, but why is car1.prototype === car? The "create" function only sets the new object's prototype to an existing object (in this case, car1's prototype points to car1)

Comment: Because that is exactly what happens when you do Object.create(car). You are essentially creating a `constructor` which would on a new instance return an object with `car` as the prototype.

Comment: Ok, but doesn't that mean that car1.prototype === car.prototype and **not** car1.prototype === car. Thanks for the prompt replies!

Comment: No. In line 2 of the function you specifically set the prototype to `o` and not `o.prototype`. It means car1.prototype === car and NOT car1.prototype === car.prototype

Comment: Not really. There is no `prototype` property on `car1`. It's the `car1`'s internal prototype pointer (where properties are looked up when not found directly on `car1`), which points to `car` because that was set as the constructors (`F`) `prototype` property.

Answer (score 1):

In your first example, you are adding to the prototype of your `car1` because `car === F.prototype` and `car1 instanceof F`. So to Q1: yes.

`Object` is the constructor function of all objects, as `F` is to your `car1`. If you add something on `Object.prototype`, it will be available on all objects - that's the reason why you should not, such non-enumerable properties mess up all for-in-loops. If you set a property of the `Object` constructor function, nothing changes for the things that inherit from it. Don't forget: `Object` equals the `F` function, not the `o` parameter for prototype setting. `new Object()` is like `Object.create(Object.prototype)`.

Answer (score 0):

That function doesn't let you select the prototype object it creates a nmew object constructor, the object argument as prototype and then return a new object based on the constructor.

That new object will inherit methods and properties from the object arguments. This is to allow the creation of new objects that inherits from others.

The reason this works (and by the way Object is a core javascript object and should not be extended)

```
Object.prototype.originCountry = "Japan";
alert(car.originCountry);   // Outputs Japan
alert(car1.originCountry);
```

and this doesn't

```
Object.carColor= "White";
```

is because the first extend the prototype object of Object, which means object build with the Object constructor will inherits those methods and properties.

When the later is what we call a static function which does not get passed to object created from the Object constructor.

I would recommend reading more about prototypal inheritance in Javascript. here is few links.

http://www.webreference.com/programming/javascript/prototypal_inheritance/index.html
http://www.htmlgoodies.com/html5/tutorials/javascript-prototypical-inheritance-explained.html#fbid=xEJ2PwtH2Oh

http://unscriptable.com/2007/04/17/inheritance-explained/